# Groovy: Sum using groupBy - List of Lists

Tags: list, groovy, sum

```
def MapTest = [:]

List b = [["abc",1.0], ["def",20.0], ["abc",300.0]]

MapTest = b.groupBy {it[0]}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.sum {it[1]}]}
```

I am trying to get the result -> [abc:301.0, def:20.0]

This code works fine in my groovy console. But somehow it's not working in an oracle product.
I get the below error. If I remove the [0] and [1] it validates, but the results are obviously wrong.

**Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#getAt(int). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.**

Maybe it's the way i am arriving at the final list thats creating the issue?? Pasting my sample code here.

```
def MappingKey = '"'+"a"+"-"+"b"+"-"+"c"+"-"+"d"+'"'
def MappingKey1 = '"'+"a"+"-"+"b"+"-"+"c"+"-"+"d"+'"'
def Data = 1
def Data1 = 5
List a = []
List b = []
a.add("$MappingKey,$Data")
a.add("$MappingKey1,$Data1")
a.each
{
b.add("["+it+"]")   // [["a-b-c-d",1], ["a-b-c-d",5]]
}
println b.groupBy {it[0]}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.sum {it[1]}]}
```

Comment: "In an oracle product" - and what could that be? Is there a stacktrace or any further information, where the error is happening? You have to `getAt` in your code (both `[...]`) -  is there some relation between the error message and which one of the two fails?

Comment: And you could try destructuring: `b.groupBy { k, _ -> k }.collectEntries {[it.key, it.value.sum { _, v -> v }]}`

Comment: Thank for the reply. Oracle PBCS. Both fails. there are two error messages for [0] and [1] - same message.

Comment: @cfrick is there any other way I can achieve the same, if you can give me an idea. Cant seem to get this to work. My whole code is dependant on this one line of code.

Comment: I have suggested an alternative.  Have you tried it and does it not work?

Comment: Issue was i was creating a list of strings instead of list of lists.

Comment: Those are no groovy list literals, you are banging strings together. It would **really** help if you would share a proper example, that shows what is going on. The new code is garbage-in-garbage-out - it does not show the `getAt` error in plain groovy.

Comment: Sorry about that. Was a silly thing to overlook, I admit. The full code is very oracle specific and this part is where I was trying to manipulate the list to get an output that i was looking for.

Comment: @cfrick The destructuring bit worked once I got all other bits working. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you have kind a `CompileStatic` groovy transformer activated in oracle

the following code will give you an error in console:

```
//this throws exception getAt not found

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def f(List b){
    return b.groupBy {it[0]}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.sum {it[1]}]}
}

f( [["abc",1.0], ["def",20.0], ["abc",300.0]] )
```

however with full type definition `List<List>` the same line works fine:

```
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def f(List<List> b){
    return b.groupBy{it[0]}.collectEntries {[(it.key): it.value.sum {it[1]}]}
}


f( [["abc",1.0], ["def",20.0], ["abc",300.0]] )
```

Comment: This is the complete error. looks like there is some static checking. I have updated my original question.  **Error:The Groovy script failed to compile with internal error: Compile Error:
[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#getAt(int). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists**

Comment: in modified question `b` variable is a `List of Strings` and not a `List of Lists`. and if you want to validate compile static in groovy console just add annotation to a function like in code above: `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic`